# Cleaning up Core Data after RestKit DELETE in Development Branch 0.20

Tags: restkit

Anyone know the latest preferred method for deleting objects from core data and a successful DELETE to the server via RestKit?

Specifically talking about the Development Branch 0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Blake (Author of RestKit):
http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-dev/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html

Basically you setup code for handling of orphaned objects (objects that exist locally, but don't come back when checked for on the server).